# Playframework jquery mobile $.ajax fileupload

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, file-upload, coffeescript, playframework-2.1

I'm going crazy trying to do a simple file upload for twitter using scribe, play framework and jquery mobile.

Please, anyone can help to set the correct parameters to send a file via $.ajax to play framework?

Controller method:

```
 public static Result postMediaJson() {

    Logger.info("**** postMediaJson ****");
    Logger.info("uid=" + uid);

    if (uid == null) {
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
        result.put("accessTokenNull", "1");
        Logger.info("8.accessTokenNull");
        return ok(result);
    }

    Token accessToken = (Token) Cache.get(uid + "accessToken");

    Logger.info("accessToken=" + accessToken);

    if (accessToken == null) {
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
        result.put("accessTokenNull", "1");
        Logger.info("9.accessTokenNull");
        return ok(result);
    }

    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, UPDATEMEDIA_RESOURCE_URL);
    service.signRequest(accessToken, request);

    Logger.info("service=" + service);

    try
    {

        String vparam = form().bindFromRequest().get("status");

        Logger.info("vparam=" + vparam);

        MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
        FilePart resourceFile = body.getFile("picture");

        if (resourceFile != null) {
            String fileName = resourceFile.getFilename();
            String contentType = resourceFile.getContentType();
            File file = resourceFile.getFile();

            Logger.info("Justo antes");

            if (file != null && vparam != null) {

                Logger.info("Entra");

                // added lines
                //String myUploadPath = Play.application().configuration().getString("myUploadPath");
                //file.renameTo(new File(myUploadPath, fileName));

                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

                Logger.info("1Entra");

                entity.addPart("status", new StringBody(vparam)); // THIS IS THE TWITTER MESSAGE

                Logger.info("2Entra");

                entity.addPart("media", new FileBody(file)); // THIS IS THE PHOTO TO UPLOAD

                Logger.info("3Entra");

                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                entity.writeTo(out);

                Logger.info("4Entra");

                request.addPayload(out.toByteArray());

                Logger.info("5Entra");

                request.addHeader(entity.getContentType().getName(), entity.getContentType().getValue());

                Logger.info("6Entra");

            }else{
                ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
                result.put("accessTokenNull", "1");
                Logger.info("10.accessTokenNull");
                return ok(result);
            }

        }else{
            ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
            result.put("accessTokenNull", "1");
            Logger.info("11.accessTokenNull");
            return ok(result);
        }

    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Logger.info("UnsupportedEncodingException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.info("IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Logger.info("NullPointerException");
        e.printStackTrace();
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
        result.put("accessTokenNull", "1");
        Logger.info("12.accessTokenNull");
        return ok(result);
    }

    Response response = request.send();

    if ( 0L == Analytic.incPokes() )
        Logger.info("Creating first poke with media of today.");

    return ok(Json.toJson(response.getBody())); 

}
```

Html page:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <a href="#pageDashboard" data-transition="slide" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-mini="true" data-direction="reverse">Volver</a>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <form id="frmPostMedia" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@routes.Application.postMediaJson()" data-ajax="false">
        <label for="taMPost">¿Qué está pasando?:</label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="7" maxlength="140" id="status" name="status"></textarea>
        <div id="lblMCount"></div>
        <input type="file" id="picture" name="picture" />
        <input type="submit" data-transition="slide" data-theme="a" data-mini="true" value="Enviar" />
    </form>     
</div>
```

And coffeescript:

```
  $("#pagePostMedia").on 'pageinit', (event) ->

      $("#frmPostMedia").on 'submit', (event) ->
event.preventDefault()
return alert "No puedes pedir apoyo con un mensaje en blanco. ¡Intenta escribir un mensaje inspirador!"if $("#status").val().length < 3  

$("#frmPostMedia").attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data")
$("#frmPostMedia").attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data")

formData = new FormData($(this)[0])

$.ajax '/postMediaJson',
type: 'POST'  
data: formData
contentType: 'multipart/form-data'
processData: false
cache : false
async: false
success: (data)->
  alert JSON.stringify(data)
error: (data)->
  alert "ERROR="+ JSON.stringify(data)

$("#pagePostMedia").on 'pageshow', (event) ->

      res = 140 - $("#status").val().length

      $("#lblMCount").html("Te quedan  <strong>" + res + "</strong> caracteres.")


   $("#status").on 'keyup', (event) ->

      res = 140 - $("#status").val().length

      $("#lblMCount").html("Te quedan  <strong>" + res + "</strong> caracteres.")
```

The result request().body().asMultipartFormData() is always null :-(

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the following:

```
contentType: false
```

I know this worked for me.  A more detailed explanation:

[Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)